# Как сделать плавную загрузку в ListView (Android)

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня есть горизонтальный progressBar.
И в начале загрузки в ListView я устанавливаю значение 
 progressBar.setMax(3000); потому что не знаю сколько примерно элементов будет загружено в ListView а потом progress + 1; что бы пошла загрузка в progressBar а в конце ставлю  progressBar.setProgress(3000); и таким образом заполняю то что не заполнилось. Получается примерно плавная загрузка.

Что я хочу чтобы можно ка-кто это сделать без установки progressBar.setMax(3000); и всех выше перечисленных манипуляций.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView lv;


    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int progress = 0;


    public Elements content;
    public ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);




            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.view);
            new NewThread().execute();

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.pro_item, titleList);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setMax(3000);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }



    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            Document doc;
            try {

                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://").maxBodySize(0).get();
                content = doc.select("tr");

                titleList.clear();

                for (Element contents : content) {
                    titleList.add(contents.text());
                    publishProgress(progress);
                }



            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

            progress = progress + 1;
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            progressBar.setProgress(3000);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

           // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}}}
```

Comment: Вариант такой: перед загрузкой ставим прогресс бар в бесконечный режим (intermediate) - потому что нам неизвестно сколько будет длиться соединение и загрузка страницы. Потом, после `doc.select` мы уже можем взять размер у `content` и выставить его как `мах`. А дальше уже публиковать прогресс. Для удобства цикл нужно изменить на индексированный, либо завести переменную, которая будет считать количество обработанных элементов и передаваться в `publishProgress` - в общем-то у вас есть `progress`, только можно сделать её локальной и инкрементить в цикле.

Comment: А как поставить   прогресс бар в бесконечный режим (intermediate) -  САМ КОД КАКОЙ??

Comment: progressBar.setMax(content); -так почему то  тоже не работает(

Comment: android:indeterminate="true"

Comment: Если кому не сложно можете  написать все как нужно на примере моего кода.Потому как progressBar.setMax(content);  у меня почему то тоже не работает(. И я не пойму android:indeterminate="true" потом нужно будет выключать.?